# clipboard in bash

Tags: bash, clipboard, line-editor

We can cut and paste current line in bash with ctl+u and ctl+y

But I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750466/2493081) that bash doesn't have clipboard concept, so how those shortkeys working?
(or in another way: what they doing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Killing and yanking text are `readline` features. `bash` normally uses `readline` but you could argue that it is not really a part of bash.

You can test that with

```
bash --noediting
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash in a terminal under X11 (most people are), then you can do cut and paste with the mouse, no keys required.

- Left click and drag to highlight.  This puts the highlighted text into the X11 primary selection.
- To paste the primary selection, put the cursor in the target window and center-click the mouse.
- You can interact with the selections on the command line using `xsel`.